# Spring Boot JPA associations vs normal SQL join

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-criteria

I have three tables:

1. company:

```
    +--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
    +--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | company_id   | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
    | company_name | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
    +--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

2. legal:

```
    +-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field       | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | id          | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
    | company_id  | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | legal_price | double  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    +-------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

3. price

```
    +------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field      | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | id         | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
    | company_id | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | price      | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    +------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

There are two one-to-many associations between `company`->`legal` and `company`->`price`. The company data in `company` is rarely changed. Data in two other tables are persisted daily. The corresponding entities are as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "company")
public class CompanyEntity {


    @Id
    @Column(name = "company_id", nullable = false)
    private Integer companyID;

    @Column(name = "company_name")
    private String companyName;


     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company", fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
                cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<LegalEntity> legal;

     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company", fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
                cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<PriceEntity> price;
```

======

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "legal")
public class LegalEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "company_id", nullable = false)
private CompanyEntity company;

@Column(name = "legal_price")
private Double legalPrice;
```

======

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "price")
public class PriceEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "company_id", nullable = false)
private CompanyEntity company;

@Column(name = "price")
private Integer price;
```

For persisting new data in `legal` or `price`, I first get the corresponding field in `company` entity with findBycompanyID:

```
    CompanyEntity cmp = crep.findBycompanyID(13);
    LegalEntity leg = new LegalEntity(cmp, 523.5);
    lrep.save(leg);
```

For querying data, I use CriteriaBuilder API:

```
      CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
      CriteriaQuery<LegalEntity> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(LegalEntity.class);
      Root<LegalEntity> root = criteriaQuery.from(LegalEntity.class);
      criteriaQuery = criteriaQuery.select(root);
      TypedQuery<LegalEntity> typedQuery = em.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
      List<LegalEntity> results = typedQuery.getResultList();
           for (LegalEntity legalEntity : results) {
                log.info(legalEntity.toString());
                }
```

This procedure could be done with a simple native SQL query:

```
SELECT c.company_name, l.legal_price from legal l
JOIN company c
ON l.company_id = c. company_id;
```

As I investigate the Hibernate SQL commands, I see:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        legalentit0_.id as id1_1_,
        legalentit0_.company_id as company_3_1_,
        legalentit0_.legal_price as legal_pr2_1_ 
    from
        legal legalentit0_
Hibernate: 
    select
        companyent0_.company_id as company_1_0_0_,
        companyent0_.company_name as company_2_0_0_ 
    from
        company companyent0_ 
    where
        companyent0_.company_id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        companyent0_.company_id as company_1_0_0_,
        companyent0_.company_name as company_2_0_0_ 
    from
        company companyent0_ 
    where
        companyent0_.company_id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        companyent0_.company_id as company_1_0_0_,
        companyent0_.company_name as company_2_0_0_ 
    from
        company companyent0_ 
    where
        companyent0_.company_id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        companyent0_.company_id as company_1_0_0_,
        companyent0_.company_name as company_2_0_0_ 
    from
        company companyent0_ 
    where
        companyent0_.company_id=?
```

My question is, which method is more efficient? I prefer using CriteriaBuilder API, since coding is quite easier and less error-prone, but I have to query the company field before each persist.

Comment: If you can do it in one SQL statement it is always more efficient than loading the whole graph of objects. Do you know the constructor expression?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli The whole thing I want to do is to inner join two tables based on one common column and get some columns from both tables.
Do you mean the stuff in JPQL?

Comment: Have a look here: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-select-clause

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Thanks. My problem is embedding different parameters in query is somehow difficult in this way. For example one user may want to change the date range or sorting order and another one may want only price info. (via a GET request with optional parameters). Should I create different queries for each situation or use some String manipulation?

Comment: You can also use Criteria API with the constructor expression. Please read the docs